# Share scope function between controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have a scope function that works on scope variables and objects.

```
$scope.myfunction = function () {
$scope.a = '';
if (($scope.c == 'a')) {
    $scope.a = 'a';
}
```

}

I want to use this function between controllers using a factory, but I have an error on `$scope` not defined. How can I gain access to scope variables from a factory?
Are there any other methods to share scope function between controllers?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to your advice I managed to solve some problem.
Now i have to understand how to solve this issue:

I have only a method in my factory. Depending from a variable it can be return a value, some values or an array.
How i can do this? Pushing these value in a temporary array and return it?

Answer (score 2):

you don't use scope in the factory.

so you have your factory

```
    angular.module('myApp').factory('myFactory', myFactory)

    function myFactory() {
        return {
            sharedMethod: function(cb) {
                ...Do Something

                if(cb) { cb(); }
            }
        }
    }
```

and then in your controller.

```
   angular.module('myApp').controller('myController', myController)

    function myController($scope, myFactory) {
        $scope.bindableMethod = myFactory.sharedMethod;
    }
```

Then you can use the method in multiple controllers.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if in sharedMethod function i have to access to scope variables, how i can do this?

Comment: Then you pass them as parameters to the factory method. Factories are isolated entities, and they should not know anything about the outside world.

Comment: I suggest using a callback method or a promise.

Comment: pass in a method to be called when your shared method is complete. so your controller specific logic is kept totally separate.